# Getting quoted string using ContentValues for insertOrThrow

Tags: android, insert, sqlite

How can i get quoted strings in a ContentValues object to be used in a sqlite insert? SQLite seems to be choking on the : of my value

```
    //inside a for loop of a NodeList
    ContentValues map = new ContentValues();
    Element elm;
    elm = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    String elmname = elm.getTagName();
    map.put("foto", getValue(elm, "foto"));
    map.put("fotonormal", getValue(elm, "foto-normal"));
    map.put("link", getValue(elm, "link"));

    myDatabase.beginTransaction();
    try {
        myDatabase.insertOrThrow(TABLE_ENDING, null, map);
        Log.i(TAG, "Added");
        myDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Transaction failed. Exception: " + err.getMessage());
    } finally {
        myDatabase.endTransaction();
    }
```

which gives me this error

```
Transaction failed. Exception: unrecognized token: ":": INSERT INTO tbl_ending (fotonormal, foto, link) VALUES (https://example.com/fotonormal.jpg, https://example.com/foto.jpg, https://example.com/);
```

i believe the SQL statement should be

```
INSERT INTO tbl_ending (fotonormal, foto, link) VALUES ("https://example.com/fotonormal.jpg", "https://example.com/foto.jpg",  "https://example.com/");
```

How can I get this output instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phillip's answer put me on the right path, I cast the return value of the function getValue as a  string

```
return (String) getElementValue(n.item(0));
```

and now i can successfully insert.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly very strange behavior. You have basically got weak typing going on in your map.put statements, which does not help. I would be inclined to explicitly cast the getValue parameters, just to see if that fixes the problem, viz:

```
map.put("foto", (String) getValue(elm, "foto"));
map.put("fotonormal", (String) getValue(elm, "foto-normal"));
map.put("link", (String) getValue(elm, "link"));
```

Comment: now i am getting error Transaction failed. Exception: error code 19: constraint failed. I believe this is related to too many quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364576/android-sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-constraint-failed